# Can I replace a NUP2105L voltage suppressor with a NUP3105L?

Tags: diodes, components, schottky, substitution, replacement

Someone gifted me a device to read *electronic control units* from cars and trucks. They gave it to me because they don't use it and they have also removed some components from it to fix another device.

I am trying to rebuild it but theres a missing component I am having troubles getting locally (I can't import it because of strict import rules we have where I live will make it hard and expensive to get) is a little smd component marked **27E** and it looks like a transistor.

After some googling I found it is a *dual bidirectional voltage suppressor* **[NUP2105L](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NUP2105L-D.PDF)**. I have no idea what that means, my knowledge in electronics is very basic.

The place where I went to buy it told me they don't have it, but I could replace it with a **[NUP3105L](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NUP3105L-D.PDF)** that they do have. But I decided to do some research to make sure.

So I tried looking at the datasheets (which I barely understand) and the first thing that makes me doubt if it will be a good substitution is that the symbol of each component looks like 4 schottky diodes, but they are pointing in opposite directions.

**My question is, would the NUP3105L be a good substitution for a NUP2105L?**

If not, is there another replacement I could use to just solder in place of the NUP2105L, without having to modify anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need it for,functionality.

It is an ESD, Load dump, Lightning protection device.

The 3105 is rated for trucks with 24V systems at a higher voltage before clamping

The 2105 is standard for 12V systems.